# How to detect SHIFT key in jQuery keydown event handler?

Tags: jquery, events, keyboard

I have the following jQuery function

```
jQuery.fn.integerMask =
function () {
return this.each(function () {
  $(this).keydown(function (e) {
    var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    // allow backspace, tab, delete, arrows, numbers and keypad numbers ONLY
    return (
              key == 8 ||
              key == 9 ||
              key == 46 ||
              key == 37 ||
              key == 39 ||
              (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
              (key >= 96 && key <= 105));
              );
      });
    });
  };
```

which is used for entry of numbers. The problem is that SHIFT+8 results in a asterisk * character being entered. It appears the "8" key in combination w/ the SHIFT is permitted. How would I prevent the SHIFT+8 from being accepted and an "*" character inserted?

Comment: it's a boolean `e.shiftKey`

Comment: To elaborate on David's comment. What you need to do is test whether e.shiftKey=true which would indicate a shift key was pressed and then return false.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function isKeyPressed(event)
{
if (event.shiftKey==1)
  {
  alert("The shift key was pressed!");
  }
else
  {
  alert("The shift key was NOT pressed!");
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body onmousedown="isKeyPressed(event)">

<p>Click somewhere in the document. An alert box will tell you if you pressed the shift key or not.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

keyword-> event.shiftKey

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_event_shiftkey